# How to print a positive number as a negative number via printf

Tags: c

While reading about printf(),I found that it can print numbers as positive or negative as desired by the user by following code(for -).But the code doesnt work and the output is a positive value.Please mention where the error is.Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  printf (" %-d\n", 1977);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you found this particular format string documented for printf?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your comments it looks like you misread [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/). The `-` and `+` specifiers do two completely different things, and neither does what you think '-' should do.

As others have noted, `-` does left justification. The `+` specifier prints positive numbers with a leading plus sign (and negative numbers still get a leading minus sign):

```
printf("%d %d %+d %+d\n", -10, 10, -10, 10);
```

outputs:

> -10 10 -10 +10

Comment: Oh!You it forces the compiler to SHOW the sign

Answer (score 4):

`%-d` Will left adjust the integer field, it won't flip the sign. Do this instead:

```
printf (" %d\n", -1977);
```

Here's the full extract from [`print(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) under **The flag characters**:

```
       -      The  converted  value is to be left adjusted on the field bound‐
              ary.  (The default is right justification.)  Except for  n  con‐
              versions,  the  converted  value  is  padded  on  the right with
              blanks, rather than on the left with blanks or zeros.  A - over‐
              rides a 0 if both are given.
```

### Update0

I see your true question now: To prepend output with the appropriate sign, use the `+` flag character to explictly show the sign. Again here is the extract:

```
       +      A sign (+ or -) should always be placed before a number produced
              by a signed conversion.  By default a sign is used only for neg‐
              ative numbers.  A + overrides a space if both are used.
```

And use it like this (The command line `printf` is mostly identical):

```
matt@stanley:~/cpfs$ printf "%+d\n" 3
+3
matt@stanley:~/cpfs$ printf "%+d\n" -3
-3
matt@stanley:~/cpfs$ printf "%+u\n" -3
18446744073709551613
```

Be aware that explicitly requesting the sign won't imply treatment of the corresponding integer as signed as in the `%u` example above.

Answer (score 4):

`printf (" -%d\n", 1977);` will output `-1997` (bad way to do it), if you would like negative numbers to become positive, do `printf (" %d\n", -1 * 1977);`  (good way to do it)

read the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) for an idea of how format specifiers work

Comment: the refrence says:Forces to precede the result with a plus or minus sign (+ or -) even for positive numbers. By default, only negative numbers are preceded with a - sign.

Comment: The reference says that for the PLUS sign.