# printf / sprintf issue with remove sign on numbers

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, printf

I have a number that may be negative or positive and I want it to pop out of sprintf() without the negative or positive sign. How would I do it?

I tried `%d` `% d` `%- d` `%+ d` `% -d` `% +d` and none of them work.

I tried gcc 4.8.2 and g++ 4.8.2 and it does not work. Is this a bug in gcc?

Comment: can you give some input?

Comment: It would be a bug if you could read in any specification that there is a way of removing the minus sign, using format strings.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ go to (space) in the flags

Comment: Can you give a complete code line? I think he meant.

Comment: Use `abs()` when you pass the value to `sprintf`

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

    void main() {
            printf("% d\n", -6000);
    }

Comment: Do as Jonathan writes. Like: `int x = -5; printf("%d", abs(x));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no format string that applies a absolute value functionality.

Here is what you have to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
  int num = -6000;
  printf("%d\n", abs(num));
}
```

- `%d` will render 34 as `34` and -34 as `-34`.
- `% d` will render 34 as  (space) + `34` and -34 as `-34`.
- `%+d` will render 34 as  `+34` and -34 as `-34`.
- `"%5d` will render 34 as (three spaces) + `34` and -34 as (two spaces) + `-34`. They both will use the field size 5.
- `"%-5d` will render 34 as  `34` + (three spaces) and -34 as `-34` + (two spaces). They both will use the field size 5, but left justified because of `-`.

Comment: so am i reading the spec wrong? i want to know if i'm reading this wrong.

Comment: I added some clarifications on how to correctly understand the spec.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779338/how-to-print-a-positive-number-as-a-negative-number-via-printf could also be useful reading

Comment: I do understand how + and - of the spec works. I'm wondering what the writer meant by "(space) If no sign is going to be written, a blank space is inserted before the value."

Comment: It means that a positive number will have a space in front and a negative number have a - in front.

Answer (score 1):

Longer and less suited, but I think it works faster.

Instead of add the math library, You can change the sign in the argument list of prinf (or sprintf) using the conditional operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n[3] = {-100, 0, 100};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", (n[i] < 0) ? -n[i] : n[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```