# Action of operating % in c language coding for negative integers?

Tags: c

Is there difference for using % for coding in c language about to evaluate positive and negative integers?for example if following form for +int is right, does its format change when integer becomes negative?

```
Int x;
printf("/n x=%d",x)
```

If s.o can answerme please if %d can be used for both +and - numbers in printf or scans or whatever.ans if not what's the correct form for negative ones?

Comment: Before asking this question you can 1) Try it. 2) Read the documentation such as [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

Comment: Yes, the negative sign will be automatically added according to the examples in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3779338/7392598

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Neither of those is a method to determine what the C standard says for `%d` in `printf`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I deliberately preferred referring to the man page instead of the standard as it is more accessible and understandable. The format specified descriptions are close enough to what they are supposed to do per the standard.

Comment: By the way, don't mistake the modulo operator `%` inside an evaluable expression with the positional marker '%' (such as %d) within a string passed to `printf`, then processed by this specific function.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Re “The format specified descriptions are close enough to what they are supposed to do per the standard”: Without specifications for what is needed (in a project, in a class, what the person wants to know for the future), you do not know what is close enough.

Comment: BTW there is not `Int` type in C. It's `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The most authoritative way to see what the C standard specifies about something is to consult [the C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).

In the 2018 version of the C standard, clause 7.21.6.1 describes the conversions performed in `printf` and `fprintf` calls. In paragraph 8, it describes the conversion specifiers, and for `d` it says:

> The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal in the style *[-]dddd*…

From this, you can see that the value may be negative, and it will be converted to a string with `-`. This paragraph says that the `int` argument is converted, and it does not specify any exceptions, so you can pass any `int` value to be converted.

In this context, brackets mean something is optional. The notation *[-]* means that `-` might or might not appear in the result. It is commonly understood that it appears if the value is negative.

### Supplement

Write `printf("x=%d.\n", x)`, not `printf("/n x=%d",x)`. C is designed for newline characters to mark the ends of lines, not the starts. In particular, when output is line-buffered, `printf("x=%d.\n", x)` will show all of its output immediately, but `printf("/n x=%d",x)` will not.